# HP Envy x360 2022 Ryzen edition speakers not working

Tags: audio

HP Envy x360 15-ey0013dx 2022 model has sound problem. In Windows 11 speakers are working perfectly fine. In Linux, the headphone jack and audio output through HDMI are working fine.

`aplay -l` output:

```
~ $ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 3: HDMI 0 [HP M27fwa FHD]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic_1 [HD-Audio Generic], device 0: ALC245 Analog [ALC245 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

`sudo inxi -Aaz` output:

```
Audio:
  Device-1: AMD Renoir Radeon High Definition Audio vendor: Hewlett-Packard
    driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel pcie: gen: 3 speed: 8 GT/s lanes: 16
    link-max: gen: 4 speed: 16 GT/s bus-ID: 04:00.1 chip-ID: 1002:1637
    class-ID: 0403
  Device-2: AMD ACP/ACP3X/ACP6x Audio Coprocessor vendor: Hewlett-Packard
    driver: snd_rn_pci_acp3x v: kernel
    alternate: snd_pci_acp3x,snd_pci_acp5x,snd_pci_acp6x,snd_acp_pci,snd_sof_amd_renoir
    pcie: gen: 3 speed: 8 GT/s lanes: 16 link-max: gen: 4 speed: 16 GT/s
    bus-ID: 04:00.5 chip-ID: 1022:15e2 class-ID: 0480
  Device-3: AMD Family 17h/19h HD Audio vendor: Hewlett-Packard
    driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel pcie: gen: 3 speed: 8 GT/s lanes: 16
    link-max: gen: 4 speed: 16 GT/s bus-ID: 04:00.6 chip-ID: 1022:15e3
    class-ID: 0403
  Sound API: ALSA v: k5.19.16-hardened1-1-hardened running: yes
  Sound Server-1: PulseAudio v: 16.1 running: no
  Sound Server-2: PipeWire v: 0.3.59 running: yes
```

`dmesg | grep snd` output:

```
[   19.279419] snd_rn_pci_acp3x 0000:04:00.5: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   20.238456] snd_hda_intel 0000:04:00.1: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   20.238555] snd_hda_intel 0000:04:00.1: Handle vga_switcheroo audio client
[   20.238745] snd_hda_intel 0000:04:00.6: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   20.300669] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0: autoconfig for ALC245: line_outs=1 (0x17/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
[   20.300678] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   20.300680] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x21/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   20.300682] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
[   20.300684] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:    inputs:
[   20.300687] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D0:      Mic=0x19
[   21.215213] snd_hda_intel 0000:04:00.1: bound 0000:04:00.0 (ops amdgpu_dm_audio_component_bind_ops [amdgpu])
```

Answer (score 0):

Even after the release of Linux 6.1, the problem is not solved yet. But I solved it by applying [this patch](https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/20220811053950.11810-1-faenkhauser@gmail.com/) and recompiling the kernel:

```diff
diff --git a/sound/pci/hda/cs35l41_hda.c b/sound/pci/hda/cs35l41_hda.c
index 129bffb431c22..21d8c2de128ff 100644
--- a/sound/pci/hda/cs35l41_hda.c
+++ b/sound/pci/hda/cs35l41_hda.c
@@ -1156,7 +1156,8 @@ static int cs35l41_no_acpi_dsd(struct cs35l41_hda *cs35l41, struct device *physd
    hw_cfg->valid = true;
    put_device(physdev);
 
-   if (strncmp(hid, "CLSA0100", 8) == 0) {
+   if ((strncmp(hid, "CLSA0100", 8) == 0) ||
+       (strncmp(hid, "CSC3551", 7) == 0)) {
        hw_cfg->bst_type = CS35L41_EXT_BOOST_NO_VSPK_SWITCH;
    } else if (strncmp(hid, "CLSA0101", 8) == 0) {
        hw_cfg->bst_type = CS35L41_EXT_BOOST;
diff --git a/sound/pci/hda/patch_realtek.c b/sound/pci/hda/patch_realtek.c
index 8a57636f622e9..e7053cbc6bb6e 100644
--- a/sound/pci/hda/patch_realtek.c
+++ b/sound/pci/hda/patch_realtek.c
@@ -9179,6 +9179,7 @@ static const struct snd_pci_quirk alc269_fixup_tbl[] = {
    SND_PCI_QUIRK(0x103c, 0x83b9, "HP Spectre x360", ALC269_FIXUP_HP_MUTE_LED_MIC3),
    SND_PCI_QUIRK(0x103c, 0x841c, "HP Pavilion 15-CK0xx", ALC269_FIXUP_HP_MUTE_LED_MIC3),
    SND_PCI_QUIRK(0x103c, 0x8497, "HP Envy x360", ALC269_FIXUP_HP_MUTE_LED_MIC3),
+   SND_PCI_QUIRK(0x103c, 0x8a31, "HP ENVY x360 2-in-1 Laptop 15-ey0xxx", ALC287_FIXUP_CS35L41_I2C_2),
    SND_PCI_QUIRK(0x103c, 0x84da, "HP OMEN dc0019-ur", ALC295_FIXUP_HP_OMEN),
    SND_PCI_QUIRK(0x103c, 0x84e7, "HP Pavilion 15", ALC269_FIXUP_HP_MUTE_LED_MIC3),
    SND_PCI_QUIRK(0x103c, 0x8519, "HP Spectre x360 15-df0xxx", ALC285_FIXUP_HP_SPECTRE_X360),
```