# How to Patch and Compile Linux Kernel for a specific issue? (No sound in HP ENVY x360 2-in-1 Laptop 15-ey0xxx)

Tags: kernel, audio, compiling, patch, hp

I got the exact same problem as the person here:
[HP Envy x360 2022 Ryzen edition speakers not working](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/722205/572281)

and I want to patch and recompile my kernel with:
https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/20220811053950.11810-1-faenkhauser@gmail.com/

I know there are a bunch of tutorials how to patch and compile the kernel, but I need this specific change that, as I understand, is not officially included in a kernel version. Correct me if I'm wrong. What do I have to do? I don't know how where start and I don't even know how to get the patch from the link.

I use Arch Linux, btw. But I am a newbie.

My Kernel Version: 6.3.1-arch2-1

Answer (score 0):

The best options are:

- Approach the Arch Linux kernel maintainer(s) via email/bug tracker and ask them to include the patch
- Wait for the next kernel release
- Try to rebuild only the appropriate kernel module: download arch's kernel, config file, apply the patch (`cd /where/the/kernel/is/unpacked; patch -p1 < fix.patch`, `make what/where/name.ko` and replace the module in `/lib/modules/linux-version/somewhere`. https://bbs.archlinux.org is where you could ask how to do that.